# Excel - Dynamic list from delimited cell / remove blanks from dynamic row

Tags: excel, formulas, array-formulas

**Program**

- Excel 2013

**Goal**

- Using data validation's List option, create an in-cell drop-down from a comma delimited list
- Using data validation's List option, create an in-cell drop-down from a clean row of values without any blanks, from a dynamically generated row that is unavoidably contaminated with blanks

**Restrictions**

- No VBA, macros, or other malarkey - formulas only
- Data is held in a row, not a column. It would be somewhat difficult to translate the data into a column, and I would prefer to avoid doing that

**Details**

My original plan was to create a single cell which contained a comma delimited list, which would then be used to create a data validation list. Upon successfully creating a nicely formatted comma delimited list, it seems that you can't simply reference the list and have it translated by the data validation tool, and now I need to find an alternate method.

The data is held in a long row (not a column, and it can't be translated to a column easily) which is generated by summing various values above it. This means that there can be a lot of blanks between two values - this is unavoidable.

The following website has an array formula that works for removing blank cells from a column, however I have had no luck translating it into a formula that works for a row:
http://www.cpearson.com/excel/NoBlanks.aspx

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(BlanksRange,SMALL((IF(LEN(BlanksRange),ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&ROWS(BlanksRange))))),ROW(A1)),1),"")
```

If anyone has any ideas on making this work for a row, I'd appreciate the help. It seems to require a bit more than just replacing the ROW() functions with COLUMN() - possibly something to do with the "1:" on the INDIRECT(), though I don't understand how the formula works enough.

I'll keep playing with it in the meantime, and of course if anyone has any other NON-VBA solutions to either the row data or the comma delimited data issue, I'm all ears.

EDIT: To clarify, there is a solution provided by the link above for taking a vertical set of data into a horizontal result lane, however this does not help with my horizontal data set.

Comment: Didn't get to the bottom of it, but try using `TRANSPOSE` rows to column, then remove blanks...

Comment: @zx8754 I did try taking a part of the data for use, but I'm having issues making the formula work anywhere other than Row 1, but thanks for the thought.

Answer (score 1):

is this what you want?

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$E$1,1,SMALL(IF(LEN($A$1:$E$1)<>0,COLUMN($A$1:$E$1),9.9E+100),COLUMN())),"")
```

I just assumed data looks like this:
Data in `Row1` and apply formula in `Row2`.

[image]

Result in `Row2` would be data in `Row1` without blanks.

**Edit1:**

I saw you need it for `Data Validation List`>
So i assume this is what you may need:

[image]

And using this formula:

```
=IFERROR(TRANSPOSE(INDEX($A$1:$E$1,1,SMALL(IF(LEN($A$1:$E$1)<>0,COLUMN($A$1:$E$1),9.9E+100),ROW(A1)))),"")
```

Hope this helps.
I'm just guessing what you want but this should give you idea on how to tweak tha array formula.